# Shopify Fraud 'Card Testing' Orders

Tags: bots, shopify, payment, credit-card, fraud-prevention

my customer has a Shopify website, and lately he's getting many "card testing fraud" orders.

I thought that Google ReCaptcha on the checkout page will solve this issue, but apparently it didn't (he still getting a lot of those orders).

I would love to understand if there's another way to prevent those orders.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is a card testing fraud? How do you book an order with a card that is fraudulent? What is a lot of these orders? Can you provide more details? What cards does your friend accept? What payment gateway is he selected to use?

Comment: Hey :) A card testing fraud is when a user or a bot is trying to test credit card numbers (usually stolen ones) in order to realize if he can use it. we get more then 100 orders like that per day. He's getting Visa, Mastercard and PayPal. He's working with Braintree as the payment gateway. All the orders blocked by the gateway or Shopify (we have a flow for it), but Braintree said that the credit card companies might block us because of it, so we need to find a proper solution for it (currently we blocked the checkout to accept logged in users only, but it's a bad solution for his business)

Comment: You do not get 100 orders a day with stolen cards, you to mean to say you get 100 attempts to buy something fraudulently per day? If you were getting 100 actual fraudulent orders per day, WOW... something amazing in the fraud world would be happening!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm getting 100 (or more) attempts  per day. But I can't understand how this semantic help with achieving a solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

We are a Shopify Plus store and had this issue back in May 2023, but working with Shopify Fraud Prevention team internally, they enabled the captcha during checkout and it stopped them 100%. If you are just enabling the captcha in the backend settings, that is not the solution because that just stops the crooks from creating fake accounts or filling out a contact us form, which is not wha they are doing. Contact Shopify Plus support and tell them you need a captcha enabled at checkout to prevent "cart testing" orders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Brian! Can you please tell me which payment provider you are using? We are also on a Plus program, but we aren't using Shopify payments so they couldn't really help us.